# jQuery loop through table with multiple element types and get values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a table I am creating from the result of a query in `PHP`. It's an editable table and when the user clicks save I need to loop through the table elements and store the text values into an array. The value from the column of Job# **must** be either at the **start** or the **end** of **each iteration** of the loop so that I can easily extract it and then use it to insert the values when I'm finished.

**PHP Table creation**

```
<?php    

if(isset($_POST['aid'])) {  
    $aid = $_POST['aid'];
    $projects = getProjects($db);
    $members = getUserName($db);            
    try {
        $project_info = $db->prepare("
            SELECT  projects.id,
                    projects.project_name,                  
                    projects.pm,    
                    projects.apm,
                    projects.est_start,
                    projects.est_end,
                    projects.contact,                   
                    projects.trips,
                    projects.tasks,
                    projects.perc_complete,
                    projects.bcwp,
                    projects.actuals,
                    projects.cpi,
                    projects.bcws,
                    projects.bac,
                    projects.comments,
                    projects.status,
                    projects.project_revenue,
                    projects.profit_margin,
                    projects.pm_perc,
                    projects.audited         
            FROM projects
            WHERE account_id = ?                        
        "); 

        $project_info->bindValue(1, $aid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $project_info->execute();       

            echo "<table class='projects_contentTable'>";           
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Job #" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Project Name" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "PM" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "APM" . "</th>"; 
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Est. Start" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Est. End" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Contact" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Trips" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Tasks" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "% Complete" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "BCWP" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Actuals" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "CPI" . "</th>";           
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Comments" . "</th>";  
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Status" . "</th>";    
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Project Revenue" . "</th>";   
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Profit Margin" . "</th>"; 
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "PM%" . "</th>";   
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Audited" . "</th>";   


            while ($row = $project_info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {             
                echo "<tr>";                            
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . "<a href='#'>" . $row['id'] . "</a>" . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td' contenteditable='true'>" . $row['project_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td'>" . 
                        "<select id='table_edit_project_pm'>" . 
                            "<option value=''>" . $row['pm'] . "</option>" . 
                            "<option>" . "-----" . "</option>";
                        foreach($members as $key => $value) {
                            echo "<option value='".$key."'>" . $value . "</option>";            
                        } 
                echo "</td>";               
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td'>" . 
                        "<select id='table_edit_project_apm'>" . 
                            "<option value=''>" . $row['apm'] . "</option>" . 
                            "<option>" . "-----" . "</option>";
                        foreach($members as $key => $value) {
                            echo "<option value='".$key."'>" . $value . "</option>";            
                        } 
                echo "</td>";               
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td'>" . 
                    "<input type='text' id='table_edit_project_start' value='". $row['est_start'] ."'>"; 
                echo "</td>";               
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td'>" . 
                    "<input type='text' id='table_edit_project_end' value='". $row['est_end'] ."'>";
                echo "</td>";               
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td' contenteditable='true'>" . $row['contact'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['trips'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['tasks'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['perc_complete'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['bcwp'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['actuals'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['cpi'] . "</td>";             
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td' contenteditable='true'>" . $row['comments'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td'>" .
                        "<select id='table_edit_project_status'>" .
                            "<option value=''>" . $row['status'] . "</option>" .
                            "<option>" . "-------" . "</option>" .
                            "<option>" . "On Hold" . "</option>" .
                            "<option>" . "In Progress" . "</option>" .
                            "<option>" . "Open" . "</option>" .
                            "<option>" . "Complete" . "</option>" .
                         "</select>"; 
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['project_revenue'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['profit_margin'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['pm_perc'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td'>" . 
                    "<input type='checkbox' id='table_edit_project_audited'>";
                echo "</td>";               
                echo "</tr>";               
            }
            echo "</table>";                
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }   
} else {    
    echo 'could not load projects table';
}

?>
```

Now the code I'm using currently to get this data looks like this

**jQuery**

```
$('.projects_editable_content_td, .projects_contentTable td:nth-child(3) a').each(function () {
    saveEdits.push($(this).text());
}); 

// then alert the values using this loop
$.each(saveEdits, function(index, value) { 
    alert(index + ': ' + value); 
});
```

When this loops through I am getting the values from Job# on saveEdits[0] and saveEdits[1] then I'm getting all the [option] values from my [select] elements. I know that this is because I somehow need to incorporate "option:selected" into this loop. Anyways, my loop is a mess and after a couple hours of messing with it I can't get this thing working.

So again, I need to loop through each tr, get the text values from each td's elements inside the tr and store the value from the Job# column at the start or end of **each** iteration of the loop.

Any help is most appreciated

Comment: why don't you just submit the form as is?

Comment: @koala_dev it's not in a form. It's an editable table. The appearance is that of an excel spreadsheet so to speak. However putting it into a form, is something I had not thought of. If you have a form based solution, post it as an answer. I'm more than willing to give it a try

Comment: Do you mean that you want to iterate over each <tr>, and within each <tr> you want to iterate over the <td>s in that <tr>? That would give you a way to grab the Job# column on each pass. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @GreatBigBore you got it my friend. That's exactly what I need

Comment: @i_me_mine Then you could just $('tr').each(function() { $(this).children('td').each(function() {}); Something like that?

Comment: @GreatBigBore yea, you could use something similar to that. Just keep in mind some of these elements are "select" HTML elements aka drop down menus so i would need something like option:selected in the loop as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I believe this will work, or at least something very much like it. Iterate through the rows one at a time, and for each row, get the text from < td >s that lack < select >s, and get the text from selected < option >s. By the way, don't forget to add < / select > in your PHP, and it wouldn't be a bad idea to add < thead > and < tbody >. Cheers.

```
$('tbody tr').each(function() {
    $('td:not(:has(select)),option:selected').each(function() {
        saveEdits.push($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much i had to run out ill check this out when I get back home

Answer (score 1):

This'll give you each row's first cell content if you put an extra class for that particular cell like `id_cell`.

PHP:

```
while ($row = $project_info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {             
  echo "<tr>";                            
  echo "<td class='content_td id_cell'>" . "<a href='#'>" . $row['id'] . "</a>" . "</td>";
```

jQuery:

```
$(".projects_contentTable tr").each(function(){
  $(this).find('.id_cell'); 
});
```

If you want to get your exact id in that cell you can do this:

```
var id = $(this).find('.id_cell').find('a').text();
```

But of course if this is what you want as I really couldn't get your question!

Comment: This table will have a lot of rows. I need to go through each tr and get the contents of each td with the class of projects_content_editable_td. I can't give them an ID when I create them because that is a loop. It would give each cell in each tr the same ID which is not allowed. Ids must be unique which is why I'm using classes.

Comment: @i_me_mine Check my edit. And it's same for other columns. My answer is restricted to Job column.

Comment: I had to run out for a bit I'll verify this when I get home. Thank you so much